# Plotting simulated logit curve in R

Tags: r, logistic, simulation

I am trying to simulate and plot a logit in R.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(boot)
n = 50
predictor = runif(n, 0,1)
outcome = rbinom(n, 1, inv.logit(predictor)) # inverse log link
glmOut = glm(outcome ~ predictor, family="binomial") ## fit logit to simulated data
predProbs = predict(glmOut, type="response") ## extract fitted probabilities
ggplot() +
  geom_rug(aes(x=predictor)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=predictor, y=predProbs))
```

I would've expected this code to give a logit s-shaped curve with positive slope, but I get something totally different: [image: 1].

I'm not sure if this is a coding error or a logic error.

Comment: Could you edit the question to clarify what the code aims to do (in words rather than / in addition to code). Some users have voted to close this as off-topic (as in about R programming, not about statistics). As this may be a logic error rather than a coding error, I think this actually is on-topic question. But that could be made clearer by focusing on the statistical logic rather than R-code.

Comment: The answer suggests the question itself was on-topic.  But the question could certainly be phrase more clearly to bring the statistical issue to the fore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact shape depend on the distribution. That means -- your seed. Try:

```
set.seed(232311)
```

and you will have a nice s-shaped-curve.

Other seeds will give you different looking curves depending on the distribution of zeros and ones. Instead of *geom_rug* you can plot the 0's and 1's to get a better idea of why the curve looks like it does.

```
ggplot() +
geom_point(aes(x=predictor, outcome)) +
geom_point(aes(x=predictor, y=predProbs), color="blue") +
geom_point(aes(x=predictor, y=predProbs)) +
ylim(0,1)
```

![image: a busy cat]